# Error when downloading files using NSURLSessionDownloadTask

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am working on an application where I want to download some files.

1. If file to download is an image, I just download it
2. If file to download is a video I need to trigger another download for the thumbnail

For this I am using NSURLSessionDownloadTask. With images everything works but when it comes to video, video itself is downloaded correctly but the thumbanil always returns an error:

> Error: URL incompatible

Here is the code:

```
- (void)download:(Message)message
               completion:(void (^)(NSArray *))completion {

NSString *mediaURL = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: message.remoteMediaUrl()];

__block BOOL isVideo = NO;
NSString* mimeType = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:message.mediaMimeType()];
if ([mimeType hasPrefix:@"video/"])
    isVideo = YES;

NSString *mediaName = [mediaURL lastPathComponent];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:mediaURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
NSString *user = [self.user];
NSString *password = [self.password];

[self.manager setTaskDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition(NSURLSession * _Nonnull session, NSURLSessionTask * _Nonnull task, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge * _Nonnull challenge, NSURLCredential *__autoreleasing  _Nullable * _Nullable credential) {
    NSString *authenicationMethod = challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod;
    if ([authenicationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPDigest]) {
        *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:user password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        return NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential;
    }
    return NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge;
}];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [self.manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

    NSURL *fileURL = [[ContentService imageDownloadDirectoryURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent: mediaName];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:fileURL error:nil];

    fileURL = [fileURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:[self getExtensionFromMimeType:message.mediaMimeType()]];
    return fileURL;
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *fileURL, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        completion(nil);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@ ", fileURL);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (isVideo) {
            NSLog(@"Download thumbnail for video");
            isVideo = NO;
            NSString *thumbnailURLAsString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: message.remoteThumbnailUrl()];
            NSString *thumbnailName = [thumbnailURLAsString lastPathComponent];
            NSURL *thumbnailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:thumbnailName];

            NSURLRequest *thumbnailRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:thumbnailURL];
            NSURLSessionDownloadTask *thDownloadTask = [self.manager downloadTaskWithRequest:thumbnailRequest progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath2, NSURLResponse *thresponse) {

                NSURL *thumbnailfileURL = [[ContentService imageDownloadDirectoryURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent: thumbnailName];
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:thumbnailfileURL error:nil];
                return thumbnailfileURL;
            } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *thresponse, NSURL *thumbnailfileURL, NSError *error) {
                if (error != nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    completion(nil);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", thumbnailfileURL);
                    completion([NSArray arrayWithObjects:fileURL, thumbnailfileURL,nil]);
                }
            }];
            [thDownloadTask resume];
        } // if isVideo 
       //////////////////////////
        else {
            completion([NSArray arrayWithObjects:fileURL, nil]);
        }
    }
}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

}

I know code is repeated but for now I wanted to have something working.
Could someone tell me what is wrong?

Also if this approach is not the right one, which one should I use?

Thanks in advance and regards

Comment: Show us the URL. That's seems to be the problem.

Comment: `[NSURL URLWithString .... ` with a `lastPathComponent` as parameter cannot work. The `scheme`, `host`, and beginning of the `path` is missing.

Comment: Yes, it was that. I fixed the url and image is correctly download. Thanks all!

Comment: **Don't edit questions to change the subject of the question**. Ask a new question. I undid the edit.